# Can I display/convert an array to a one-line compact form?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If I run the code below:

```
$family = array ("father" => "Bill", "mother" => "Cathrine", "kids" => array("Adam", "Emma", "Nick"));

var_export($family);
```

.. it will result in the following output:

```
array (
  'father' => 'Bill',
  'mother' => 'Cathrine',
  'kids' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Adam',
    1 => 'Emma',
    2 => 'Nick',
  ),
)
```

I wonder if there's a simple way to display the array in a more compact 1-line-form, like this (or similar):

```
[father: Bill, mother: Cathrine, kids: [0: Adam, 1: Emma, 2: Nick]]
```

Can it be done (e.g. using some kind of implode), or is the only solution to iterate through the arrays elements and generate a compact string?

Comment: json_encode() looks good except for a few additional characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use json_encode() function for this.
Read this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Just try this:

```
$x = json_encode($family);
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Why on earth would you go and wrap it in `var_dump` ;-) Just `echo` it clean.